# psycopg2.errors.IdleInTransactionSessionTimeout

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

Today I want to share with you the following inconvenience with psycopg2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Mar 8 14:21:24 812495ebf967 mi-app-dev INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'order_id_1': 6056197, 'param_1': 1}
Mar 8 14:21:24 812495ebf967 mi-app-dev   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
Mar 8 14:21:24 812495ebf967 mi-app-dev     self.dialect.do_execute(
Mar 8 14:21:24 812495ebf967 mi-app-dev   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 609, in do_execute
Mar 8 14:21:24 812495ebf967 mi-app-dev     cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
Mar 8 14:21:24 812495ebf967 mi-app-dev   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbapi_opentracing/psycopg2_tracing.py", line 38, in execute
Mar 8 14:21:24 812495ebf967 mi-app-dev     return self._traced_execution(self._cursor_factory.execute, self, *args, **kwargs)
Mar 8 14:21:24 812495ebf967 mi-app-dev   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dbapi_opentracing/tracing.py", line 145, in _traced_execution
Mar 8 14:21:24 812495ebf967 mi-app-dev     val = func(*args, **kwargs)
Mar 8 14:21:24 812495ebf967 mi-app-dev psycopg2.errors.IdleInTransactionSessionTimeout: terminating connection due to idle-in-transaction timeout
Mar 8 14:21:24 812495ebf967 mi-app-dev SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
```

I am using the next connections:

```
import logging
from contextlib import contextmanager

from sqlalchemy import Table
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

from ..models.base_model import Base


class DataAccessLayer:

    def __init__(self, base_model: Base):
        self.engine = None
        self.Session = None
        self.Base = base_model

    def connect(self, db_connection: str):
        self.engine = create_engine(db_connection, pool_size=20, max_overflow=0, pool_pre_ping=True, echo=True)
        self.Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=self.engine))

    @contextmanager
    def transaction(self):
        session = self.Session()
        try:
            yield session
            session.commit()
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(e)
            session.rollback()
            logging.warning('session rolled back')
            raise
        finally:
            session.close()
            logging.info('session closed')

    def get_session(self) -> Session:
        return self.Session()

    def reset_db(self) -> None:
        self.Base.metadata.drop_all(self.engine)

    def create_all(self) -> None:
        self.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=self.engine)

    def drop_table(self, table: Table) -> None:
        table.drop(self.engine)
```

I don't understand very well what is happening with the connection because we are controlling the exception. However, we are receiving this error, :(, if you could help me I really appreciate it, sorry, I am working on my English skills, beforehand thankyou very much

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be idle (no selects/updates/...) with postgres queries,
and Postgres could close connection (before your code reach commit) based on it `IdleInTransactionSessionTimeout` settings in config => you can change postgress config for you logic with Idle or reconnect to postgres in case you don't need transaction.